# i want to convert my library .so file into the .jar file of the android project.

Tags: android

I have converted "test.apk" of my Android project file into Java code. but i am not able to convert my lib .so file into the .jar file. I am new in android and i have tried to built a application as my college project under the guidance but he didn't provide us the .jar file there are .so file. can any one help. Thanks in advance.i m really looking forward to it.

Comment: I am not having much idea about this but i have the same problem . I just copy the .so files to my working android application . It works.

Answer (score 1):

JAR files are for compiled Java code. `.so` files are for compiled native code. You cannot "convert [your] lib .so file into the .jar file".